# Deploying app on heroku, getting runtime.txt issue

Tags: python, machine-learning, heroku, error-handling, deployment

I have built a python app on python version '3.10.7' but this is not supported by the current heroku stack which is 22. So I updated the python version to '3.10.8' which is also recommended by heroku itself. But still getting the same error. How to fix this issue, Please help

Using Python version specified in runtime.txt

!     Requested runtime 'python-3.7.10' is not available for this stack (heroku-22).

!     For supported versions, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.

!     Push failed

PS: I am using git and github for deploying app. If this info could be of any help

Comment: You've typed 3.10.7 (a minor release of Python 3.10), but the error refers to 3.7.10 (a minor release of Python 3.7). Python 3.7 is not supported on the Heroku 22 stack, but Python 3.10 is. In any case, you think you've updated to 3.10.8 but the error does not reflect that. Did you _commit_ the modified `runtime.txt`? Are you sure you're deploying from a branch that contains that commit?

Comment: Yes, I committed and pushed the changes to GitHub. I have created only one branch. Here is GitHub [link](https://github.com/abhikashyapr22/Mushroom_Classification)

Comment: Try adding a newline to the end of your `runtime.txt` file. I also suggest that you use `python-3.10.8`, not `python-3.10.7`, as that is [currently supported](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes).